# Convergence in probability of $\frac{1}{n \ln (n)} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}$ to $\frac{1}{\ln (2)}$ for i.i.d RVs with $ P\left(X_{1}=2^{k}\right)=2^{-k}$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, independence, probability-limit-theorems

Let the random RVs $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, \ldots$ be independent and identically distributed such that $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=2^{k}\right)=2^{-k}$ for $k=1,2,3, \ldots$. I want to prove that
$$
\frac{1}{n \ln (n)} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k} \text { converges in probability to } \frac{1}{\ln (2)}
$$
I tried to go directly with the definition of the convergence in probability and make use of the law of large numbers but the $\mathbb{ln}(n)$ is what got me stuck

Any suggestions

Comment: This sum converges in probability to 0.

Comment: This is a standard exercise using truncation. See the truncation section here for example: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/275a-notes-3-the-weak-and-strong-law-of-large-numbers/